# stop camera click sound programmatically in android

Tags: android

I am using android's default camera to click images from within my app. I want to stop the click sound that it does on clicking an image. Is there a way to stop that click sound programtically?

Thanks.

Comment: Telephones are required to make a click sound by law in some countries. look here for example: http://www.opencongress.org/bill/111-h414/show

Answer (score 6):

I was able to successfully use the trick to turn the volume down. I did this just before taking the picture:

```
    AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
```

And this just after getting the first message back:

```
    AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I modified this slightly by using setStreamVolume(). The benefit being that I can first call getStreamVolume() and later restore the system to its original setting.

Answer (score 3):

To disable sound use this code:

```
AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int streamType = AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM;
mgr.setStreamSolo(streamType, true);
mgr.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
mgr.setStreamMute(streamType, true);
```

To enable sound use this code:

```
mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
streamType = AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM;
mgr.setStreamSolo(streamType, false);
mgr.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
mgr.setStreamMute(streamType, false);
```

Comment: you can use this code also for silent:
AudioManager audioMngr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioMngr.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

for normal mode:
audioMngr.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

Answer (score 1):

For my Nexus S running 4.0.3,

```
AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM
```

does not prevent camera shutter sound from emitting
,
but

```
AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC
```

works!

Answer (score 0):

You can mute and unmute your device using the code below:

```
 final AudioManager mode = (AudioManager)   this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 //Silent Mode Programatically
 mode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

//Normal Mode Programatically
mode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```