# Playing audio simultaneously with camera shutter sound

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

How do I play a sound simultaneously with the camera shutter going off?

In my application, I have an inset camera preview. It takes 3 pictures automatically after 5 seconds of the activity starting. During this time the application is receiving a range of values via Bluetooth. Everytime the values are greater than a preset threshold, the application plays a tone, which is done using MediaPlayer.

The problem is that when the camera goes off, the shutter click sound seems to take over all the audio, and the tone being played stops and only resumes after the 3 shutter clicks. I don't want to silence the camera shutter, so is there a way I can get the tone to play with shutter clicks? This is all happening in one activity.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use the hidden `ENFORCED_AUDIBLE` stream type for your tones. This is the stream type that the camera shutter sound most likely will use, so it won't be muted unless the shutter sound has been muted.

Note that this stream type wasn't introduced until ICS (or maybe it was GB/HC, I can't say for sure off the top of my head), so it won't be compatible with every version of Android in existence. The integer value for this stream type identifier is 7, but if you want to check if exists / get its value programmatically you might be able to do so using reflection on the `AudioSystem` class.

Here's an example of how this could be done:

```
public static boolean mHasEnforcedStream = true;
public static int STREAM_SYSTEM_ENFORCED = 0;

...

static
{        
    try
    {
        Class asClass = Class.forName("android.media.AudioSystem");
        Field sseField = asClass.getDeclaredField("STREAM_SYSTEM_ENFORCED");
        STREAM_SYSTEM_ENFORCED = sseField.getInt(null);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        mHasEnforcedStream = false;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that if you use this stream type you'll always get your tones in the loudspeaker even if the user has e.g. a 3.5mm wired headset attached, and even if the user has put his/her phone in silent mode.

Comment: I could not find information about `ENFORCED_AUDIO` in the standard Android documentation. It looks like AudioSystem is no longer a class that is open anymore.

Comment: It's a hidden stream type, which is why I suggested using reflection to check for its existence. See my code example above to get an idea of how this can be done.

Comment: Thanks Michael! I got it to work now. But it looks like enforcing it sets the volume to the maximum and the tone comes out at full blast. I haven't been able to turn it down, and am suspecting it ignores that.

Comment: Yeah, it will always play at max volume since this stream is intended mainly for camera shutter sounds in markets where they have legal requirements saying that people shouldn't be able to mute/attenuate the shutter sound and go around taking photos of other people without their knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you should need. This should contain what you need. The first link is probably more useful than the 2nd since you want to still have other sounds, though its possible you'd be able to disable the audio channel specific to the camera shuttle sounds.

- [Is there any way to replace or silence the camera shutter sound in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289481/is-there-any-way-to-replace-or-silence-the-camera-shutter-sound-in-android)
- [stop camera click sound programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594018/stop-camera-click-sound-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: I don't want to play another sound in place of the shutter sound. I want it to play over the tone. The tone could begin playing at anytime. If the tone begins playing before the camera goes off, then I want to hear the tone still playing while the camera shutter clicks over it.

Answer (score -1):

Well since I am still new to programming, I would do a google search on what files give off the camera sound, and I would put in your app to where it would rename those files with different extension so the sound would not go off and have them rename back to the original files. OR I would look on how to make the camera silent through changing the camera values. I know on my Samsung Galaxy SIII I had to change the camera file names. (sprint carrier)